# Rollback for bulk copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, rollback, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I have an application that make a copy from my database by bulk copy class in c#.

Can I rollback the bulk copy action in sql server when occur an exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MSDN article: [Performing a Bulk Copy Operation in a Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tchktcdk(v=vs.100)#Using-Existing-Transactions) 
or the newer documentation: [Transaction and Bulk Copy Operations | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/transaction-and-bulk-copy-operations#using-existing-transactions)

```
using (SqlTransaction transaction = destinationConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy( destinationConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction))
    {
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```