# Will SqlBulkCopy Close method commit/Dispose external transaction?

Tags: c#, sqltransaction

I have a SQL Bulk copy function which has following code to create a bulk copy instance.

```
 SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection) WorkConnection,
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers, (SqlTransaction) WorkTransaction);
```

"WorkTransaction" is an external transaction. What will happen to it

1. If we use "using" block around the SqlBulkCopy. Will it dispose this external transaction ?
2. If we call close function ( "bulkCopy.Close();"), will it commit/dispose external transaction ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rollback for bulk copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216254/rollback-for-bulk-copy)

Comment: I highly doubt it as that would defeat the point, but it sounds easy to test for yourself. Fire up SQL Profiler and run your code. If you see a `COMMIT`, the answer is yes, if you don't, then the answer is no.

Comment: Calling `Dispose()` (Putting it in a "using" block) calls the `Close()` function. See the Remarks section of the [Close method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.close(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

No.  The point of supplying an external transaction to `SqlBulkCopy` is to allow other operations to be included in the transaction, so unless an error occurs, SqlBulkCopy will not terminate the transaction.

From the [MS Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can specify an existing SqlTransaction object as a parameter in a
>   SqlBulkCopy constructor. In this situation, the bulk copy operation is
>   performed in an existing transaction, and no change is made to the
>   transaction state (that is, it is neither committed nor aborted). This
>   allows an application to include the bulk copy operation in a
>   transaction with other database operations.

Comment: From what you just pasted, why are you saying "unless an error occurs"? It sounds like even if an error occurs it doesn't affect the transaction state?

Comment: thanks...I ahve read this. But it does not talk about closing Bulkcopy.

Comment: Yes it does, *"no change is made to the transaction state"* that means it will not affect the state, even if you dispose/close the class.